# Tabular cell alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, mdframed

I feel like this is a noob question, but I've been busting my chops trying to find an answer to this.

I'm trying to create a table with two side by side paragraphs. They don't appear side by side when using a regular tabular. The problem can be worked around if I use `\parbox`, but occasionally I want to be able to use `\mdframed` on one side.

How do I get these two cells to line up?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{.4\textwidth} | p{.58\textwidth}}


Hello from the other side.\\
I must have called 100 times.\\


&


To tell you I'm sorry for everything that I've done
But when I call you never seem to be home
Hello from the outside
At least I can say that I've tried
To tell you I'm sorry for breaking your heart
But it don't matter. It clearly doesn't tear you apart anymore.
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{l | l}


\parbox[t][][t]{.4\textwidth}{Hello from the other side.\\
I must have called 100 times.\\
}

&

\parbox[t][][t]{.58\textwidth}{
To tell you I'm sorry for everything that I've done
But when I call you never seem to be home
Hello from the outside
At least I can say that I've tried
To tell you I'm sorry for breaking your heart
But it don't matter. It clearly doesn't tear you apart anymore.
}

\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{l | l}


\parbox[t][][t]{.4\textwidth}{Hello from the other side.\\
I must have called 100 times.\\
}

&

\parbox[t][][t]{.58\textwidth}{
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue]
To tell you I'm sorry for everything that I've done
But when I call you never seem to be home
Hello from the outside
At least I can say that I've tried
To tell you I'm sorry for breaking your heart
But it don't matter. It clearly doesn't tear you apart anymore.
\end{mdframed}
}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: one column uses `b`, the other `p`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: you have aligned the baseline of each cell of the first column with the top of the second, use p for both

Comment: You're both right. However, the output doesn't change even when both are  `p`. I'm editing the question to reflect that.

Comment: Repalace `\\ ` with `\newline` or `\par`.

Comment: @salimbou That works unless I'm using `mdframed`

Comment: A work around, you can add `\vspace*{-2\mdflength{innerleftmargin}}` before every `mdframed` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your problems are answered in comments (see *Johannes_B* and *salim bou*), regarding `mdframed` you probably want, that text is aligned. This can be possible only in case, if you use `mdframed on left side too but with white lines  (that on white paper aren't visible):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdframed}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{.4\textwidth} | p{.58\textwidth}}
Hello from the other side.\newline
I must have called 100 times.
    &   To tell you I'm sorry for everything that I've done
        But when I call you never seem to be home
        Hello from the outside
        At least I can say that I've tried
        To tell you I'm sorry for breaking your heart
        But it don't matter. It clearly doesn't tear you apart anymore.
    \end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{.4\textwidth} | p{.58\textwidth}}
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=white]
Hello from the other side.\newline
I must have called 100 times.
\end{mdframed}
    &   \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue]
        To tell you I'm sorry for everything that I've done
        But when I call you never seem to be home
        Hello from the outside
        At least I can say that I've tried
        To tell you I'm sorry for breaking your heart
        But it don't matter. It clearly doesn't tear you apart anymore.
        \end{mdframed}
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

To have less vertical space before and after `mdframed` environment, you need redefine parameters accordingly.